# How to 'mimic' reconnecting HDMI cable from linux?

Tags: linux, audio, hdmi

Occasionally, my Ubuntu 20.04 machine 'forgets' that it should output audio through the HDMI cable; in fact, the "Output" tab in the "Sound Preferences" does not mention the HDMI connection at all. The connection itself is fine though, because it still passes on video.

Replugging the HDMI cable fixes the audio. However, that makes the screen forget certain settings (YCbCr444) about the connection that require more manual intervention to recover.

There are many ways to solve the XY-problem of the occasionally broken audio. Currently I was wondering whether I could somehow mimic reconnecting the HDMI cable without actually physically unplugging the cable; any ideas?

My expectation is that even if it would be possible to 'reconnect' through software, that that still would make the screen (a TV) forget it was ever connected to the computer, but I don't have a good mental model of HDMI handshakes to be sure.